# Formula in Array VBA excel

Tags: arrays, excel, vba, formula

I am putting data in my array I created in VBA.

I wrote some formulas in the macro but when I paste them it is not working.

```
Sub Button3_Click()

Application.Calculation = xlManual

'update list of document

'declare variables

Dim i As Long
Dim m As Long
Dim n As Long
Dim j As Long
Dim lNumColumn As Long

Dim XLsheetD As String
Dim range_data As String

Dim tab_data()


Dim Data As ListObject
Dim track_list As ListObject

'ini Data

Set Data = Sheets("track_list").ListObjects("sheets_list")
Set track_list = Sheets("track_list").ListObjects("track_list")

Application.Goto Reference:=track_list
Column = ActiveCell.Column
Row = ActiveCell.Row - 1

range_data = "A9:A6000"

'import list

m = Data.ListRows.Count
nb_docs_prev = 0
n = 0
lNumColumn = Application.CountA(Sheets("track_list").Range("B6:Z6"))

For k = 1 To lNumColumn

If Range("B6").Offset(0, k - 1) = "manual" Then
GoTo nextcol
End If

n = 0

    For i = 1 To m

    XLsheetD = Data.DataBodyRange(i, 1)

    lNumCases = Application.CountA(Sheets(XLsheetD).Range(range_data))

    nb_docs = lNumCases - 1

    c = Data.DataBodyRange(i, k + 1)

    If c = "-" Then
    n = n + lNumCases
    GoTo nextsheet
    End If

    If k = 1 Then
    ReDim Preserve tab_data(lNumColumn, nb_docs + nb_docs_prev + 1)
    End If

        For j = 0 To nb_docs

        If Range("B6").Offset(0, k - 1) = "hyperlink" Then
        tab_data(k - 1, n) = ""
        Else
        tab_data(k - 1, n) = Sheets(XLsheetD).Range("A9").Offset(j, c - 1)
        End If

        n = n + 1

        Next j

    nb_docs_prev = nb_docs + nb_docs_prev + 1

nextsheet:

Next i

nextcol:

Next k

'Put data in order

lNumCases = track_list.ListRows.Count

'==>test if data already in the table

For p = 1 To n

For q = 1 To lNumCases

If track_list.DataBodyRange(q, 1) = tab_data(0, p - 1) Then

For r = 1 To lNumColumn

If Range("B6").Offset(0, r - 1) = "manual" Or Range("B6").Offset(0, r - 1) = "semi-automatic" Then
    If tab_data(r - 1, p - 1) <> "" Then
    Else
    tab_data(r - 1, p - 1) = track_list.DataBodyRange(q, r).Formula
    End If
End If

Next r

End If

Next q

Next p

' formulas for new lines

For p = 1 To n

tab_data(5 - 1, p - 1) = "=IF([@[DCN no]]<>"""",INDEX(DCN!R9C3:R229C3,MATCH([@[DCN no]],DCN!R9C1:R229C1,0)),"""")"
tab_data(11 - 1, p - 1) = "=IF([@[DCN no]]<>"""",IF(INDEX(DCN!R9C7:R229C7,MATCH([@[DCN no]],DCN!R9C1:R229C1,0))<>"""",""CLOSED"",""OPEN""),"""")"

Next p

'paste list

Application.Goto Reference:=track_list
Selection.ClearContents

track_list.Resize Range(Cells(Row, Column), Cells(Row + n, Column + track_list.ListColumns.Count - 1))

Application.Goto Reference:=track_list

Selection = Application.Transpose(tab_data())


Application.Calculation = xlAutomatic

End Sub
```

Do you know why ?

Before doing that my macro was working. It is just those formulas impossible to paste.

Thanks

Comment: Do you get an error? Or does that run, but the formula isn't as you expect?  Try turning on the Macro Recorder, then enter those formulas manually in Excel.  Then, stop the Recorder, go to Options --> Formulas, and turn on R1C1 style.  Then you'll have the skeleton of your formula, and just double up on the quotes when putting in VBA.

Comment: The error is "Run-time error '1004':

Comment: I record already the formula this way. I am sure it is good. It just because of the array.

Comment: your second formula cannot be correct it is missing any type of `=`,`>`, or `<` in the second IF().  Also it is missing a `)`

Comment: Ok it was a typo in my question. It is not the problem anyway.

Comment: What about `tab_data(5 - 1, p - 1).FormulaArray = [your formula]`?

Comment: Error Invalid qualifier

Comment: Use the `Formula` property of the `Range` object: `Range("S8:AY250").Formula = Application.Transpose(tab_data())`

Answer (score 0):

Your statement

```
Range("S8:AY250") = Application.Transpose(tab_data())
```

Can only be used to write the values of tab_data to the worksheet

You need to explicitly write your array formula to the worksheet via the method Bruce Wayne identified.

```
Range("S8").formulaArray = "=IF([@[DCNno]]<>"""",INDEX(DCN!R9C3:R229C3,MATCH([@[DCNno]],DCN!R9C1:R229C1,0)),"""")"
```

Will get you closer to where you want to be, but the above cell reference is undoubtedly wrong, and I can't determine which cell you actually need, since you're using variables in your array elements

Comment: emjaySX I pasted the full macro. The error is at the command selection =  Application.Transpose(tab_data())